# Spring's transaction to thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I defined a bean called A in spring configuration and A used spring's transaction.Obviously,when I use A's methods,we are in the transaction. But if A is a thread,what will happen when A start(),is it still in transaction and is it the same condition as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A extends Thread, and A's `start()` method is transactional, then Spring will do as for all the other transactional methods: a transaction will start (if not already started) when start() is called, and the transaction will end as soone as `start()` returns (if it began when `start()` was called).

The `run()` method of A will be executed in another thread, outside of any Spring transaction. If this `run()` method calls a transactional method of another, injected, Spring component, then this method will be executed inside a Spring transaction.

Comment: A good response,and I also want to know how can I let run() method be in a spring transaction.

Comment: Just make `run()` delegate to another transactional Spring bean method. run() itself won't be transactional.